# Using numpy.datetime in numba nopython functions?

Tags: numpy, numba

Is it possible to create NPDatetime objects within a @jit(nopython=True) function?  From what I can tell, initializing these objects requires using string objects which seems to prevent nopython functions from compiling.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly do operations on numpy datetimes.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def diff_dt(a, b):
    return a - b

x = np.datetime64('2005-02-25')
y = np.datetime64('2005-02-27')

diff_dt(x, y)
```

You however can't create a datetime object it appears:

```
@nb.njit
def create_dt(s):
    return np.datetime64(s)

# Fails
create_dt('2005-02-25')
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass an array of numpy datetimes?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out immediately, but you might look in the numba tests to see if you can figure it out https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/a4e6d6689d11ddad4125a01c4e4ad19bc69c5759/numba/tests/test_npdatetime.py

Comment: Its currently not possible to use datetimes in numba. Numba allows datetime64 datatype but nopython=True doesnt work for datetime64 arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar problem. What I did was just convert my datetimes into integer seconds since the epoch, then after the jit operation, recast them to datetimes.